# array_key_exists for compound key in array

Tags: php, compound-key, array-key-exists

How do I check to see if a compound key exists with array_key_exists such as

```
$myarr['ind1']['ind2']
```

Would like to see if the key ['ind1']['ind2'] exists in $myarr.

I googled this and looked at some similar answers but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`isset`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/isset) to check for an array member that not equals `NULL`, which is the case for a compound array and safe to assume in your case:

```
if (isset($myarr['ind1']) && array_key_exists('ind2', $myarr['ind1'])
{
   ...
}
```

If `$myarr['ind2']` potentially never equals to `NULL` you can do the following, which might show better what you're trying to check:

```
if (isset($myarr['ind1']['ind2']))
{
   ...
}
```

This checks the compound key does exists and is not `NULL`.

Comment: yes, it seems like isset check is the easiest way to get what I am after.  thought this would return an error if the keys didn't exist but it doesn't.  thx

Answer (score 4):

```
if(array_key_exists("ind1", $myarr) && array_key_exists("ind2",$myarr["ind1"])) {

}
```